# Ubuntu 22.04 how do I remove google drive from favorites

Tags: unity, nautilus

Yesterday I updated to 22.04, which looks very nice.
There is one thing which I would like to change on my system.
On the Ubuntu dock is a link to Nautilus opening my Google Drive.
While having Nautilus access to my Google Drive is nice, I don't see that I will use it very often. Thus I would like to remove it from the dock (the access is available in nautilus itself, just above "Other locations".)

Nearly all icons on the dock have as one of the options "Remove from Favorites". The google drive link has only (in right click) New Window and Mount, with nothing about removing the icon.

So my question is: how do I remove this relatively useless icon? It seems clear that it is something which can be done, but how?

The link is the 3rd item, below Chromium.

[image: 3rd icon in list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item that you see in Nautilus is ruled by the Online Account in Ubuntu Settings. To manage its visibility you need to:

- Open the Activities menu or the Application Grid menu and start typing "Online Accounts"
- Click on Online Accounts to open the panel.
- On the right side, select your Google account
- Disable or enable the item called "File".

The item that you see in the Ubuntu dock is by the "*Show mounted volumes and devices*" option. You can disable it by running in a terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false`

or enable it by running:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts true`

It's important to note that:

- You can have both items (in Nautilus and in Ubuntu dock) enabled.
- You can have both items (in Nautilus and in Ubuntu dock) disabled.
- You can have the item in Nautilus and not in Ubuntu dock.
- You cannot have the item in Ubuntu dock and not in Nautilus, because the icon in the dock will be visibile only if the Google Drive disk is set in Nautilus, nevertheless the value of "show-mounts" option.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer has 2 effects: 1) it removes the link on the favorites and 2) it removes the link in nautilus (above Other Locations). 1 is good and 2 is not good. Can I get 1 and not 2?

Comment: Please, could you [edit] the question adding a screenshot of the original scenario, if you are able to restore the orginal situation?

Comment: Good idea, screen shot has changed, but I found it.

Comment: Now I understood, answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 has a native support for tweaking these things. Go to Settings, Appearance, scroll to the way bottom and select "Configure dock behavior".

Switch on "Show Volumes and Devices" for showing your mounted drives;

The rest is a self explaining:
Tick "Include Unmounted Volumes" for showing your unmounted volumes;
Tick "Include Network Drives" for showing network drives;
Switch on "Show Trash" for Trash to be on the bar;

Cheers.